# Isomorphic graph and adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory

We know that two graphs are isomorphic iff their adjacency matrices are similar via a permutation matrix. But if the adjacency matrices are similar, does it imply the graphs are isomorphic?

This question Any proof or counterexamples are welcomed, thank you!

Comment: No. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory#Isospectral_graphs .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks!But I wonder how to prove that the same multiset of eigenvalues in adjacency matrices implies similarity.

Comment: If your graphs are undirected, this follows by the spectral theorem (which implies that adjacency matrices are diagonalizable).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Got it! You can make it an answer so that I can select as the best answer.